# Why can't there be a third minimal normal subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups

"Suppose that N and K are minimal normal subgroups of the primitive group G. Then each of N and K is transitive; but they centralise one other, and so each is semiregular, and so regular. But then it is not possible for there to be a third minimal normal subgroup."

Is the last statement true because there are only two regular representations of a group - the right and left? If so, what is the reason there can only be two regular representations?

Comment: Is the first paragraph your own words, or are you copying it from somewhere? If copied, you're supposed to put it in quotation marks or a block or something to communicate that.

Comment: thank you - done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a result that the centralizer of the image of the left regular permutation representation of a group $G$ is equal to the image of the right regular representation, and the claim follows from this, which is related to the fact that there are only two regular representations.

So, if there are two minimal normal subgroups then they must be the images of the left and right regular representations of some group, which must be the direct product of copies of a nonabelian simple groups.

The smallest such example has degree 60 with $N \cong K \cong A_5$.

Comment: What is it exactly that implies that there cannot be a third type of regular representation?

Comment: As I said, the centralizer of $N$ is $K$ and vice versa. A third such subgroup would have to centralize them both!

Comment: right, right, yes!